# How to check a service starts after reboot or not?

Tags: debian, root, debian-based

I have been given to check if NTP service start after reboot or not and this one I have to check without rebooting the server, as it is in production mode. How can I do? Also I have to check if NTP running as a service or not. In different servers I got different output e.g Server 1

remote           refid  st t when poll reach delay offset jitter

10.4.255.254 192.5.41.41 2 u  61   64    7   6.930 0.504   1.059 
10.4.255.234     .STEP. 16 u  -    64    0   0.000 0.000   0.000 
142.54.181.202   .STEP. 16 u  -    64    0   0.000 0.000   0.000 
108.61.56.35     .STEP. 16 u  -    64    0   0.000 0.000   0.000 
67.18.187.111    .STEP. 16 u  -    64    0   0.000 0.000   0.000 
66.228.59.187    .STEP. 16 u  -    64    0   0.000 0.000   0.000

remote           refid       st t when poll reach delay offset jitter

+198.58.100.237 127.67.113.92 2 u 499 1024   377 33.140 5.155  2.999 
66.228.35.252   64.90.182.55  2 u 78h 1024   0   69.489 16.223 0.000 
*38.229.71.1    172.16.32.4   2 u 43m 1024   374 53.205 -1.768 6.905 
+208.53.158.34164.244.221.197 2 u 136m 1024  200 56.359 -0.910 1.860

Server 3
remote         refid      st t when poll reach delay offset jitter

*10.4.255.254 192.5.41.41 2  u 366  1024 377   1.011 0.642  0.557 
10.4.255.234  .STEP.      16 u -    1024 0     0.000 0.000  0.000

What can I conclude from this..??

Answer (score 0):

use either of these commands:

```
 service ntp status

ps aux | grep ntp
```

the second command will show you the pid ntp is using

if you need to restart the service you can use:

```
service ntp stop
service ntp start
```

you can also use this command to check the status of all services:

```
 service --status-all
```